# How to post data with webview2

Tags: c#, wpf, webview2

I need a post request for a login. I'm using the webview2 package in WPF and using it.

My code is this:

```
  HttpRequestMessage request = new HttpRequestMessage(HttpMethod.Post, new Uri("Sample_url"));
        request.Content = new FormUrlEncodedContent(new[] {
            new KeyValuePair<string, string>("email", email),
            new KeyValuePair<string, string>("password", "123"),
        });
     // webview2 does not contain a defenition for 'NavigateWithHttpRequestMessage'
     Browser.NavigateWithHttpRequestMessage();
```

what i want to do is login the user in first then show him the view.

Comment: See this: https://learn.microsoft.com/da-dk/dotnet/api/microsoft.web.webview2.core.corewebview2.navigatewithwebresourcerequest?view=WebView2-dotnet-1.0.721-prerelease&viewFallbackFrom=webview2-dotnet-1.0.664.37#Microsoft_Web_WebView2_Core_CoreWebView2_NavigateWithWebResourceRequest_Microsoft_Web_WebView2_Core_CoreWebView2WebResourceRequest_

Comment: can explain to me in a simple example post request with Browser as webview2 declared in xaml ? thank you

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Using `WebView2 version 1.0.790-prelease` (probably even earlier), you can create a `CoreWebView2WebResourceRequest` object using `webView.CoreWebView2.Environment.CreateWebResourceRequest()`.
This can then be passed to `NavigateWithWebResourceRequest`.

So, for example:

```
var request = webView.CoreWebView2.Environment.CreateWebResourceRequest(navigateData.Url, 
              "POST", postData, "Content-Type: application/x-www-form-urlencoded");
webView.CoreWebView2.NavigateWithWebResourceRequest(request);
```

Comment: If you set your `postData` as null, then the browser won't actually navigate, nor will it throw an exception.

Answer (score 1):

Ok, this is not as easy as I thought, when I gave you that link.

First, `CoreWebView2.NavigateWithWebResourceRequest(CoreWebView2WebResourceRequest)` is only included in the `pre-release` version of `WebView2`.

Second, `CoreWebView2WebResourceRequest` does not have a public constructor, so you can't actually use it (outside the `WebResourceRequested` event handler).

This is clearly a 'pre-release' thing that isn't ready to be used yet.

**So, what do you do?**

Well, I suggest, you use the method, I have used for some time:

```
1. Navigate to the login page, using the `Source` property.
2. Get the names of the `input` elements for 'email' and 'passwords'.
3. Construct some javascript to set the values of those 2 elements and perform a `click` on the button, that posts the form.
```

That should log you in.

Comment: actually i got a get route and passed my api-token so im login with that now but thanks. i might construct some javascript.